# How to compare two arrays in c# and find the exact match of arrays

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to compare two array in c#. If they are matched go to if condition else go to the else condition. How can we do that in c#.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] numbers2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I want to compare the two arrays like

```
if(numbers == numbers2){
   do something
}else{
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.SequenceEqual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method. It does exactly what you want:

```
if (numbers.SequenceEqual(numbers2)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a extension function for array, which takes input another array object and then using  [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can compare two arrays. Like -

```
if (numbers.ArrayEqual(number2){
// do this
}
else{
// do that
}

function static bool ArrayEqual(this int[] a, int []b)
{ 

  return a.Length == b.Length 
                         && new HashSet<string>(a).SetEquals(b);
}
```